# Outside click on Ipad device not working for a Div Close

Tags: jquery, ipad

I am trying to close a div block if they click outside of that div in ipad , but its not working.

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong

```
    if (IOSDevice()) // this is custom function
        {                       
            $(document).bind('touchstart',function(event){     
                // alert(event.target.id);          
                if(event.target.id !="MyDivId"){
                    $('#MyDivId').hide()
event.stopPropagation();
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#MyDivId').length) {
        $('#MyDivId').hide()
    }
});
```

Comment: Does jquery1.7 support on?

Comment: thanks for the answer , I will try that and let you know how it works

Comment: does the closest needs to pass id along with # closest('#MyDivId')

Comment: @kobe Yes, sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: I just tried its not working , its still getting closed. Basically its a div wrapped with some child divs also , is there any otherway of doing this?

Comment: wow its working , i didn't give the shell container ID before..you are rocking million thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can also add multiple selectors in container variable

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function (e) {
var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            container.hide();
        }
});
```